# TikZ: Arrowhead color defined by an option for another command

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I was studying the PGF manual when I faced the following behaviour.

Referring to the code below, I specified a `latex` arrowhead *after* the `\filldraw` element and the arrowhead is drawn of the same color of the border of said element. However, if I specify a non standard arrowhead *before* the `\filldraw` or if I use a standard arrowhead after the `\filldraw` the output is displayed correctly. Moreover, `latex` type arrowhead in the `\foreach` element are displayed correctly in red.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \draw [help lines,step=0.5cm] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw [-latex] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
  \filldraw [fill=green!20,draw=green] (0,0) -- (0.3,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=30,radius=0.3cm] -- cycle;
  \draw [-latex] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
  \draw [->,rotate=45,dashed] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);% <-- standard arrowheads are not affected
  \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330}%<-- just to highlight the problem
    \node [draw,thick,red,circle,minimum size=.8cm,
           pin={[pin edge={latex-,red,thick,shorten <=1pt}]\x:$$}] at (1.5,0) {};%<-- these arrows are not affected
\end{tikzpicture}\\
My PGF version is \pgfversion.
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is going on here? Am I making a basic mistake?

Comment: This looks like a bug. You need to add `[arrows={-latex[color=black]}]` option.

Comment: @percusse: I tried to add your code to the global `tikzpicture` options (i.e. after `scale=3`) but the second arrowhead is still green.

Comment: No I mean in the second arrowhead you have to explicitly set the color to black. That's why I think it is a bug

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment of @percusse : this looks like a bug !

When we use `draw=some color` this color is used afterward by some arrows.

And in a strange way `node` reset this behaviour.

Here is another minimal example :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw=orange] (0,0) circle(1cm); % this draw color is used after by some arrows
  \draw[ultra thick,|->] (0:-1) -- (0:1); % the standard and | arrows are not affected
  \draw[ultra thick,stealth-latex] (90:-1) -- (90:1); % the latex and stealth arrows use the previous draw color
  \node {}; % node reset the draw color !
  \draw[ultra thick,stealth-latex] (45:-1) -- (45:1); % now it is ok
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]